# Replace all occurrences in a string by another string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have this string:

```
"487351.25373014854 - 152956.2387091797 P_1(x) +
14288.881396831219 P_2(x) - 708.4250106547449 P_3(x) +
22.029508388530736 P_4(x) - 0.46451906903633394 P_5(x) +
0.006931166409021728 P_6(x) - 7.493824771409185e-05 P_7(x) +
5.934862864562062e-07 P_8(x) - 3.442722590115344e-09 P_9(x) +
1.4457000568406937e-11 P_10(x) - 4.276159814629395e-14 P_11(x) +
8.446505496408776e-17 P_12(x) - 9.998295324026605e-20 P_13(x) +
5.362954837187194e-23 P_14(x)"
```

I'm trying to replace all `P_n(x)` by `*(x**n)`.

For example:

```
"1 - 2 P_1(x) + 3 P_2(x) - 708.4250106547449 P_3(x)"
```

would return:

```
"1 - 2*(x**1) + 3*(x**2) - 708.4250106547449*(x**3)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub()` to replace all occurrences of that pattern.

```
import re

s = "1 - 2 P_1(x) + 3 P_2(x) - 708.4250106547449 P_3(x)"

pattern = r' P_(\d+)\(x\)'  # (\d+) captures the n in P_n
replace = r' * (x**\1)'     # \1 uses the last captured n as a replacement

s_2 = re.sub(pattern, replace, s)
print(s_2)
```

Output:

```
1 - 2 * (x**1) + 3 * (x**2) - 708.4250106547449 * (x**3)
```

And with your full input:

```
s_3 = """487351.25373014854 - 152956.2387091797 P_1(x) +
14288.881396831219 P_2(x) - 708.4250106547449 P_3(x) +
22.029508388530736 P_4(x) - 0.46451906903633394 P_5(x) +
0.006931166409021728 P_6(x) - 7.493824771409185e-05 P_7(x) +
5.934862864562062e-07 P_8(x) - 3.442722590115344e-09 P_9(x) +
1.4457000568406937e-11 P_10(x) - 4.276159814629395e-14 P_11(x) +
8.446505496408776e-17 P_12(x) - 9.998295324026605e-20 P_13(x) +
5.362954837187194e-23 P_14(x)
"""

s_4 = re.sub(pattern, replace, s_3)
print(s_4)
```

Output:

```
487351.25373014854 - 152956.2387091797 * (x**1) +
14288.881396831219 * (x**2) - 708.4250106547449 * (x**3) +
22.029508388530736 * (x**4) - 0.46451906903633394 * (x**5) +
0.006931166409021728 * (x**6) - 7.493824771409185e-05 * (x**7) +
5.934862864562062e-07 * (x**8) - 3.442722590115344e-09 * (x**9) +
1.4457000568406937e-11 * (x**10) - 4.276159814629395e-14 * (x**11) +
8.446505496408776e-17 * (x**12) - 9.998295324026605e-20 * (x**13) +
5.362954837187194e-23 * (x**14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple for loop with the `replace()` function

```
for i in range(n):
    mystr = mystr.replace('P_'+str(i)+'(x)', '*(x**'+str(i)+'2)')
```